# Matlab PDE Toolbox can't solve advection-diffusion

Tags: matlab, scientific-computing, pde

Out of curiosity, I checked Matlab's PDE toolbox and found out that it can't solve the advection-diffusion equation [according to the documentation here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/equations-you-can-solve.html).

In the PDE written in the documentation, you only have the diffusion term but no advection term. Is there any reason why? For such a standard equation, I would have expected that Matlab is able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

[**Traditional finite-element methods**](https://de.mathworks.com/products/pde.html) such as the  **traditional Galerkin FE** which [seems to be implemented in Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/basics-of-the-finite-element-method.html) struggle (e.g. unphysical oscillations in the solution) with [non-selfadjoint equations such as the parabolic advection-diffusion equation](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_finite_element_method_not_popular_method_for_solving_fluid_problems) without modifications to the numerical scheme.

You might be able to do that nonetheless by [**specifying a non-constant f**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/f-coefficient-for-specifycoefficients.html). I *currently do not have access to a Matlab license* but according to the documentation you can access the structures state that should contain the passive scalar and its gradients and location containing the coordinate locations. This should enable you to prescribe either a constant velocity or to construct an analytical velocity profile (such as a [Poiseuille](http://www.thermopedia.com/content/1042/) profile) with the coordinate locations. (Maybe it is also possible to use a point-wise velocity profile in that function somehow as well?)

Try to set **m = 0**, **d = 1**, **c = D** (diffusion coefficient), **a = 0** and **calculate f** using the two **structures state** (state.ux, state.uy, state.uz  which are the gradients of the transported scalar u) and **location** (location.x, location.y and location.z) to impose an analytical velocity profile. The following pseudo-code should yield a diffusion-advection equation with a constant velocity in x-direction.

```
% set density
rho = 1;

% set viscosity
D = 1;

% set constant velocity
vel = [1, 0, 0];

% set coefficients for diffusion equation
specifyCoefficients(model,'m',0,...
                          'd',rho,...
                          'c',D,...
                          'a',0,...
                          'f',@fcoeffunction);

...

%% function for determining f
function f = fcoeffunction(location,state)

    f = - rho*( vel(1)*state.ux + vel(2)*state.uy + vel(3)*state.uz); %calculate f from constant velocities

end
```

This theoretically should give you the advection-diffusion equation. Basically we model the advection part by an **artificial source term** that accesses the gradients of the scalar quantity. This is similar to what you can do in 1D with [pdepe](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html) where you can access the gradient with dudx.